# Google Sheets - COUNTIFS with date within one year

Tags: google-sheets

I currently have...

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"example",F:F,"example2")>0
```

This is working as intended. It checks to see if the phrase "example" is in column B and the phrase "example2" is in column F. If the row contains both of these phrases in each of the appropriate columns, it outputs TRUE.

What I am trying to add is a third criteria. Column A is where the user inputs a date. If that date is within one year of today's date, the background color changes to green. If the date is not within one year of today's date, the background color changes to red. I would like to add this condition to my `COUNTIF` formula listed above.

If this row contains a date that is within one year of today's date, if it contains the phrase "example" in column B, and if it contains the phrase "example2" in column F, it is TRUE.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Whoops, should have clarified. The dates in Column A will always be in the past. So "within one year" means within 364 days of today's date in the past. Is that explained enough?

Comment: The output is "1"

Even if the correct phrase is not listed in Column F, the output stays "1." Basically the output seems unaffected by the three criteria in one row (date within one year, correct phrase in column B, correct phrase in column F). Additionally, is there a way to change what the output says?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xDulpO06_AzsiSbpRETO8n12RyCbKr31Yr7XTe6jt4w/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to show if four different text strings in Column B also have a correct date within 364 days of todays date (Column A) and the correct text string in Column F. If all three criteria are correct, I want it to display TRUE or FALSE in the top right corner under summary. I'm not trying to track the number of correct rows, just if all three criteria are met.

Comment: The formula in cell `H5` seems to be working fine. Add `>= 1` to the end of formula to get a `true`/`false` value. Edited the answer.

Comment: Inserted in `I2:I5` a version of the formula that uses values in F2:F5 as filter criteria. Perhaps that is what you are really after?

Comment: Yes! That works and I guess it really does boil down to the Pass/Fail in Column F. I'm still new to google sheets so I will study your formula. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```excel
=counta( 
  iferror( 
    filter(
      A1:A, 
      isnumber(A1:A), 
      datevalue(A1:A) <= today(), 
      datevalue(A1:A) + 364 >= today(), 
      B1:B = "example", 
      F1:F = "example2" 
    ) 
  ) 
) >= 1
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).